# How to fix "Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not
> exist in
> var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
>
> #1 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
>
> #2 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
>
> #3 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(849):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
>
> #4 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(804):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
>
> #5 /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(774):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
>
> #6 /var/www/blog/vendor/ in /var/www/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 734

Comment: Add use Log; in your controller

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you should be adding Log to your namespaces,  as per @BobB comment.

For example in a controller it could be.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controller;

use Log;
...
```

or call Log with a global namespace

```
\Log::
```

I'd also suggest reading about namespaces in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php